# Error with creating bean 'slicedResourcesAssembler' when Spring HATEOAS added to POM

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, spring-mvc

When I add Spring HATEOAS to pom.xml, i receive this error while trying to start my project. I use Spring Security, but project cannot start. When I remove Spring HATEOAS and Spring Plugin Core, problem does not exist. But I need to use HATEOAS in my project.

errors:

```
2023-07-19T16:32:19.228+02:00 ERROR 10588 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'slicedResourcesAssembler' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/data/web/config/HateoasAwareSpringDataWebConfiguration.class]: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.web.SlicedResourcesAssembler]: Factory method 'slicedResourcesAssembler' threw exception with message: org/springframework/hateoas/SlicedModel
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:659) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:493) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1332) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1162) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:560) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:973) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:941) ~[spring-context-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:608) ~[spring-context-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:733) ~[spring-boot-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:435) ~[spring-boot-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:311) ~[spring-boot-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1305) ~[spring-boot-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1294) ~[spring-boot-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at com.example.demo.DemoApplication.main(DemoApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.web.SlicedResourcesAssembler]: Factory method 'slicedResourcesAssembler' threw exception with message: org/springframework/hateoas/SlicedModel
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:171) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:655) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/hateoas/SlicedModel
    at org.springframework.data.web.config.HateoasAwareSpringDataWebConfiguration.slicedResourcesAssembler(HateoasAwareSpringDataWebConfiguration.java:106) ~[spring-data-commons-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:139) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    ... 20 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.hateoas.SlicedModel
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520) ~[na:na]
    ... 26 common frames omitted
```

I don't use Spring HATEOAS anywhere in my project, tried `mvn clean install` and adding

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.plugin</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-plugin-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

but when I try to add this dependency, I receive even more exceptions, for example:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'httpSecurity': Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.HttpSecurityConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setContentNegotiationStrategy' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setConfigurers' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'hypermediaWebMvcConfigurer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/hateoas/config/WebMvcHateoasConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'hypermediaWebMvcConfigurer' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'hypermediaWebMvcConverters' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/hateoas/config/HateoasConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'hypermediaWebMvcConverters' parameter 1: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.hateoas.mediatype.hal.HalMediaTypeConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Error creating bean with name '_relProvider' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/hateoas/config/HateoasConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method '_relProvider' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'relProviderPluginRegistry': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation

My pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jakarta.validation/jakarta.validation-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.28</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mockito/mockito-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.12</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>6.2.4.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.15.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.hateoas</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-hateoas</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.1</version>
        </dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.plugin</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-plugin-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.modelmapper</groupId>
            <artifactId>modelmapper</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be version compatibility issues with Spring HATEOAS and Spring Boot 3.1, consider removing version specification, allowing Spring Boot to manage versions automatically:

```java
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.hateoas</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-hateoas</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.plugin</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-plugin-core</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: You gave me a perfect hint! I just realized that I used legacy versions of both dependencies. Although you still need to specify version. Thank you!